# How to create/display different data arrays and objects, without using a framework?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to two object X and Y

```
const x = {
      '10112021': '1.72',
      '11112021': '3.18',
      '12112021': '3.15',
      '13112021': '4.88',
      '14112021': '3.00',
      '15112021': '3.43',
      '16112021': '1.38',
      '17112021': '1.44',
      '18112021': '4.22',
      '19112021': '2.50',
      '20112021': '2.91',
      '21112021': '3.83',
      '22112021': '4.30',
      '23112021': '2.14',
      '24112021': '4.19',
      '25112021': '2.03',
      '26112021': '4.98',
      '27112021': '0.06',
      '28112021': '0.92',
      '29112021': '3.38',
      '30112021': '2.54',
      '31112021': '0.88',
      '01112021': '4.19',
      '02112021': '2.98',
      '03112021': '4.70',
      '04112021': '3.86',
      '05112021': '2.72',
      '06112021': '0.49',
      '07112021': '0.85',
      '08112021': '1.44',
      '09112021': '1.73',
    };

const y = {
  '10112021': '2.80',
  '11112021': '4.51',
  '12112021': '4.12',
  '13112021': '1.59',
  '14112021': '3.19',
  '15112021': '4.70',
  '16112021': '4.57',
  '17112021': '4.33',
  '18112021': '1.94',
  '19112021': '4.32',
  '20112021': '2.52',
  '21112021': '1.49',
  '22112021': '4.89',
  '23112021': '4.69',
  '24112021': '4.74',
  '25112021': '1.49',
  '26112021': '1.64',
  '27112021': '2.70',
  '28112021': '3.36',
  '29112021': '4.73',
  '30112021': '3.15',
  '31112021': '4.97',
  '01112021': '0.68',
  '02112021': '1.80',
  '03112021': '4.58',
  '04112021': '1.43',
  '05112021': '4.96',
  '06112021': '2.55',
  '07112021': '2.40',
  '08112021': '1.35',
  '09112021': '4.54',
};

const dates = [
  {
    date: '15-11-2021',
    label: 'Monday, 15 November',
  },
  {
    date: '16-11-2021',
    label: 'Tuesday, 16 November',
  },
  {
    date: '17-11-2021',
    label: 'Wednesday, 17 November',
  },
  {
    date: '18-11-2021',
    label: 'Thursday, 18 November',
  },
  {
    date: '19-11-2021',
    label: 'Friday, 19 November',
  },
  {
    date: '20-11-2021',
    label: 'Saturday, 20 November',
  },
  {
    date: '21-11-2021',
    label: 'Sunday, 21 November',
  },
];
```

How do I merge two objects and array in JavaScript so that I get only the unique items from each array in the same order they were inserted into the original arrays?

**The result after merging as below :**

> [
> {
> date: '15-11-2021',
> data: {
> x: '3.43',
> y: '4.70',
> },
> },
> {
> date: '16-11-2021',
> data: {
> x: '1.38',
> y: '4.57',
> },
> },
> {
> date: '17-11-2021',
> data: {
> x: '1.44',
> y: '4.33',
> },
> },
> {
> date: '18-11-2021',
> data: {
> x: '4.22',
> y: '1.94',
> },
> },
> {
> date: '19-11-2021',
> data: {
> x: '2.50',
> y: '4.32',
> },
> },
> {
> date: '20-11-2021',
> data: {
> x: '2.91',
> y: '2.52',
> },
> },
> {
> date: '21-11-2021',
> data: {
> x: '3.83',
> y: '1.49',
> },
> },
> ]

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far, to achieve your desired result. The code you have attempted may simply require some minor changes to get it working as expected & our community members may be able to guide you to fix your code.

Comment: I'm very new to this, so can't think any further. can help me ? @jsN00b

Comment: @PutraIrawan you are being asked to show what you have tried. SO will not write you code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comment:

> I'm very new to this, so can't think any further. can help me ?

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// helper method to transform date into obj-key format
const convertDateToKey = dt => dt.replaceAll('-', '');

// method to "merge" x & y data into "arr" array
const myMerge = (arr, xobj, yobj) => (
  arr.map(                  // iterate over the "arr" array
    ({ date }) => ({        // destructure to access "date"
      date,                 // populate "date" to output as-is
      ...(                  // if "transformed" date is present in both "x" & "y"
        convertDateToKey(date) in xobj &&
        convertDateToKey(date) in yobj 
        ? {                 // populate the "data" with both "x" and "y" values
          data : {
            x: x[[convertDateToKey(date)]],
            y: y[[convertDateToKey(date)]]
          }
        }                   // if either "x" or "y" does not have value for "date"
        : {}                // do not have any prop named "data" in result
      )
    })
  )
);

const x = {
      '10112021': '1.72',
      '11112021': '3.18',
      '12112021': '3.15',
      '13112021': '4.88',
      '14112021': '3.00',
      '15112021': '3.43',
      '16112021': '1.38',
      '17112021': '1.44',
      '18112021': '4.22',
      '19112021': '2.50',
      '20112021': '2.91',
      '21112021': '3.83',
      '22112021': '4.30',
      '23112021': '2.14',
      '24112021': '4.19',
      '25112021': '2.03',
      '26112021': '4.98',
      '27112021': '0.06',
      '28112021': '0.92',
      '29112021': '3.38',
      '30112021': '2.54',
      '31112021': '0.88',
      '01112021': '4.19',
      '02112021': '2.98',
      '03112021': '4.70',
      '04112021': '3.86',
      '05112021': '2.72',
      '06112021': '0.49',
      '07112021': '0.85',
      '08112021': '1.44',
      '09112021': '1.73',
    };

const y = {
  '10112021': '2.80',
  '11112021': '4.51',
  '12112021': '4.12',
  '13112021': '1.59',
  '14112021': '3.19',
  '15112021': '4.70',
  '16112021': '4.57',
  '17112021': '4.33',
  '18112021': '1.94',
  '19112021': '4.32',
  '20112021': '2.52',
  '21112021': '1.49',
  '22112021': '4.89',
  '23112021': '4.69',
  '24112021': '4.74',
  '25112021': '1.49',
  '26112021': '1.64',
  '27112021': '2.70',
  '28112021': '3.36',
  '29112021': '4.73',
  '30112021': '3.15',
  '31112021': '4.97',
  '01112021': '0.68',
  '02112021': '1.80',
  '03112021': '4.58',
  '04112021': '1.43',
  '05112021': '4.96',
  '06112021': '2.55',
  '07112021': '2.40',
  '08112021': '1.35',
  '09112021': '4.54',
};

const dates = [
  {
    date: '15-11-2021',
    label: 'Monday, 15 November',
  },
  {
    date: '16-11-2021',
    label: 'Tuesday, 16 November',
  },
  {
    date: '17-11-2021',
    label: 'Wednesday, 17 November',
  },
  {
    date: '18-11-2021',
    label: 'Thursday, 18 November',
  },
  {
    date: '19-11-2021',
    label: 'Friday, 19 November',
  },
  {
    date: '20-11-2021',
    label: 'Saturday, 20 November',
  },
  {
    date: '21-11-2021',
    label: 'Sunday, 21 November',
  },
];

console.log(
  'merge dates with x, y values...\n',
  myMerge(dates, x, y)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've also included the result of the merged arrays, wouldn't this post tell you enough?

[Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)